# Is there python code to convert nltk.tag taggedsent_to_conll (-U?) into conll-x format?

Tags: python, nltk

I'm uncertain whether taggedsent_to_conll output is in CoNLL-U format, although posts/replies by others seems to suggest that it is.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I did a Google search with "conll-u to conll-x", got

https://github.com/UniversalDependencies/tools

README refers to the following perl script: conllu_to_conllx.pl